# Different Results on Different System

Tags: java, io, temp

When I use this code at my home PC, it gives the output as "output1" ,But
when i use the same code at my office PC gives a different  output as "output2".

**code:**

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
```

- Output 1: `C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\`
- Output 2: `C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp`

  Why there is a difference in output?

Comment: Is it the same Java, the same Windows?

Comment: it takes from TMP environment variable, check it on home and office PC

Comment: Should be your environment variable value. I don't think it's relevant to Java.

Comment: yes it is same java version and same OS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These outputs which the java gives from executing 
`System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));`
     is taken from the **TMP environment variable set in the system**...

Check there...

There will be a difference in the path for environment variable set there.